# How to disable package updates from a source while enabling updates from others?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, wine, jack

I am currently using `jackd2` version `1.9.19~dfsg-2ubuntu1` from the jack2 ppa ([https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jackd2/1.9.19~dfsg-2ubuntu1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jackd2/1.9.19%7Edfsg-2ubuntu1)). However, apt really wants to update from the kxstudio repo (https://kx.studio/Repositories) instead, despite being incompatible for Ubuntu wine (https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).
I have dealt with this for the last couple of months by `apt-mark hold`ing the package but it would be better if there was a way to disable the kxstudio specifically for this package.

Edit: The kxstudio are not specifically for jack, it also contains other software I use and want to receive updates for.

Comment: Hello. what version of Ubuntu are you using? Did you add the PPA for this  kxstudio repo (https://kx.studio/Repositories)?

Comment: 21.10. Yes, I installed their repo .deb which automatically installed a couple of PPAs

Comment: So if you removed that PPA it would not update that software. From your question that would seem to fix it.

Comment: But I have other packages I want to keep which receives updates from these kxstudio repos

Comment: the kxstudio PPAs weren't specifically for jack, it also had other software I use

Comment: See here how this works: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/02/set-package-ppa-apt-repository-priority-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be controlled by setting priorities in the APT system.

Create a configuration file under `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`, eg. `/etc/apt/preferences.d/kxstudio`, and tell there that `jackd2` should not come from this PPA if there is a decent alternative, as follows:

```
# Never prefer other packages from the kstudio repository
Package: jackd2
Pin: release o=####
Pin-Priority: 1
```

To find the value of ###, the string that specifies the origin, run the command `apt-cache policy` and see the value for `o=` below the line for the PPA in question.

Set Pin-Priority to a negative value to prevent that version from ever being installed, even if it is available nowhere else.